# Trigger function when Undeploying application

Tags: java, glassfish, quartz-scheduler

How do I automatically trigger Java function to stop Quartz scheduler jobs when I deploy/undeploy/redeploy JEE5 application in Glassfish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and hook on `contextDestroyed()`.

Basic example:

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Write code here which should be executed on webapp startup.
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Write code here which should be executed on webapp shutdown.
    }

}
```

and register it as a `<listener>` in `web.xml`.

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you get to JAVA EE-6+, annotate a class with @WebListener and implement ServletContextListener on that class to get a shutdown notification. No need to deal with web.xml. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)